# How to center 3 divs horizontally with itselfs?

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem:

I want to put 3 divs horizontally with itself, but i'm not getting to do it right.

Could someone help?

I've already searched a lot about properties in css and html, but i couldn't apply to what i'm doing.

With the normal zoom:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuYpb.png

[image: With the normal zoom:]

What i want: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmy1f.png
[image: What i want:]
Codes:

```css
    .container {
  width:100%;
  border-color: #FF0000; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width:medium;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
 }
 
 .menu_box_filtro{
  display:inline;
 }
 
 .conteudo_box_filtro{
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="border_preta">
  <div class="menu_box_filtro">      
    <div class="grid_10 border_brown conteudo_box_filtro">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_box_filtro">    
    <div class="grid_63 border_brown conteudo_box_filtro">
      menu centro
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu_box_filtro">
    <div class="grid_10 border_brown conteudo_box_filtro">
      menu direita
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with `align-items: center`.

Comment: @Shadowen how could i do it? I would have a parent: display:inline-flex; and a child with: align-items: center; ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using FlexBox.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #FF0000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu_box.left {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100px;
}

.menu_box.center {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  height: 200px;
}

.menu_box.right {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu_box left">Left</div>
  <div class="menu_box center">Center</div>
  <div class="menu_box right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2aFA/192/)

```
<div class="main">
<div class="inner">
<div class="left-col">Left</div>
<div class="center-col">Center</div>
<div class="right-col">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```css
.container{
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#F0A202;
}

.group{
content:"";
display:table;
clear:both;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 36%;
  float: left;
 
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4%;
  
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 26%;
  float: right;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container group">
  <div>
    <p>First<p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Second<p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Third<p>
  </div>
</div>
```